# Add to Cart Button on my HTML Code

Tags: php, html

Can somebody help me on how the Add to Cart button works? I created a website (Computer parts store) and I don't know how the Add to Cart button works. I have 9 Sample products per components (9 components) So basically I have 81 Products in my website. 1 Product goes like this. How can I sell my items?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="../../images/i3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <br>
                    <dl>
                    <dt>
                        Intel Core i5-4430 Haswell Quad-Core 3.0 GHz LGA 1150 84W BX80646I54430 Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4600
                    </dt>
                    <br>
                    <br>    
                </dl> 
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" style="float:right;">Add to Cart</a>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>




<div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    <b>Series: </b>Core i7<br>
                    <b>L3 Cache: </b>8MB<br>
                    <b>L2 Cache: </b>4 x 256KB<br>
                    <b>Cooling Device: </b>Heatsink and fan included<br>
                    <b>Model #: </b>BX80646I74790<br>
                    <b>Item #:</b> N82E16819116987<br>
                    <b>Return Policy: </b><br>
                    <i>Replacement Only Return Policy</i>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <p>
                <b>Price: </b></br>$319.99<br>
                <b>Shipping: </b>$2.99
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: For this purpose it's best to use a ready to use shop system (like magento). Writing such an application yourself needs quite some effort (also regarding security aspects).

Comment: create session in php to store item in cart